# How can I retrieve the complete record with the maximun value grouped by another in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table (it's a big query in fact, so don't use joins over the table please) as follows:

```
date     | priority | data
20200301 | 1        | 0.3
20200301 | 2        | 0.4
20200302 | 2        | 0.4
20200302 | 3        | 0.1
20200303 | 1        | 0.8
```

So, I want the date and the data with the LOWEST priority of each date, so the result of the query I'm looking for would be:

```
date     | priority | data
20200301 | 1        | 0.3
20200302 | 2        | 0.4
20200303 | 1        | 0.8
```

Whenever I try to make a group by clause, that query cannot retrieve the data column nor support different values on the data column.

Comment: What's the expected result if there are multiple rows with the same priority for the same date?

Comment: That cannot happen, the pair (date, priority) is unique @Marth .

Comment: Can we use an anti-join, please?

Comment: @wildplasser for performance reasons, I cannot use that table two times on the query because It is the result of a heavy query. If anti-join let you do what we want without using that table more than once it's okey.

Comment: Without any indexes, even the row_number() solution below will require a sorting step, which basically is a complete pass over the table (or: worse).

Comment: If you use common table expressions then this result set can be materialised, so needing to scan it multiple times does not imply building the result set multiple times. A window function-based colution like the one @Marth proposes would work well.

Comment: Even without an index, `distinct on (zdate)` appears to be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a the `row_number` window function for this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    "date"     INTEGER,
    "priority" INTEGER,
    "data"     FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO t
    ("date", "priority", "data")
VALUES ('20200301', '1', '0.3')
     , ('20200301', '2', '0.4')
     , ('20200302', '2', '0.4')
     , ('20200302', '3', '0.1')
     , ('20200303', '1', '0.8');


SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY priority)
    FROM t
) f
WHERE row_number = 1
```

returns:

```
+--------+--------+----+----------+
|date    |priority|data|row_number|
+--------+--------+----+----------+
|20200301|1       |0.3 |1         |
|20200302|2       |0.4 |1         |
|20200303|1       |0.8 |1         |
+--------+--------+----+----------+
```

---

As mentioned by @david in the comments, it might be more efficient to filter the rows based on "priority = min_priority_for_date" (instead of ranking them and filtering them afterwards):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (date, priority) IN (
    SELECT date, MIN(priority)
    FROM t
    GROUP BY date
)
```

Comment: Bear in mind that when you use `row_number`, or ranking functions, the query execution inherently needs more memory allocation and processing because it has maintain the ordering of potentially multiple rows per partition - right up to the point where you throw all but one of them away. So finding the minimum value and then filtering on that can be a performance and memory saver.

Comment: Cool I mean you could also use a `min()` window function.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: I'm not sure I understand then :). Do you mean a query with a top-level `SELECT min(priority) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY priority /* could also use a first_value() ? */` along with a `DISTINCT ON (date)` ?

Comment: Oh I meant you could use that `min(priority) over(partition by date) as min_priority by date` clause (you wouldn't need the `order by`), and in an outer query do `priority = min_priority_by_date.